# Maven: Deployment time filtering

Tags: maven

In my projet I have xml files in the application resource directory that contain property place holders. The place holders are then filtered from a filter file, say `app.filters`, at  build time by maven. The `app.filters` file contains parameters like database user name, password, connection string, sftp hostname, paswword, directory etc. The values of these parameters are different based on the environemnt the application is deployed in - dev, test, prod etc. Currently I build the project seprately for each environment with different `app.filters` file.

I was wondering if there is a way, using maven, to build the project once for all environtments and then provide a different filter file at deployment time based on the environemnt to materialize the xml resource files.

Comment: Whats wrong with this question? Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

If as you say you want a single portable build (good idea, BTW) then it is not a Maven issue. Maven helps build your application. Once you have built your EAR/WAR/whatever Maven is out of the picture. At run time (not deploy time) you can have your application look for the appropriate configuration file on its classpath.

Make sense?

Comment: Maven is not only for building a jar file. Maven already has `deploy`, `install`, `exec` plugins that follow the `build` stage in lifecycle. Its not unrealistic to ask for resource filtering during any of these stages.

Comment: I never said Maven is only for building a JAR.  Nor did I say that what you were attempting is unrealistic.  Your original email asks "if there is a way, using maven, to build the project once for all environments".  **That** is what I addressed.  _Now_ you are talking about resource filtering **during** the build.  Which _do you want_?  Processing a resource file at runtime would have to be **your application's logic**.  Maven is not involved here.

Comment: As in my original posting, I am still looking for a way to perform `deployment` time resource filtering using maven. Since maven already provides `build` time filtering and maven is getting involed in a project lifecycle beyond build, it has become a maven issue. If it can not be done currently with maven or its plugins, its a feature needs to be added in a future release.